# Can I be certain that there is a stud here?

Tags: studs

I'm looking to mount a TV across the gap of a recessed window.  The window is set a few inches back from the wall.  The plan is to sink two screws into studs on either side of the window to fix the large VESA mount there, and then hang the TV on it.

[image: stud finder lighting up at alleged center of stud]

As depicted, the stud finder I've been using detects stud centers about 5/8 - 3/4" from the edge of the window alcove.  This was indicated consistently on both sides of the window, up and down a couple of feet.

I drilled preparatory holes to sink the screws, and I think what came out was wood, but I'm not entirely certain.

There was also a little bit of curved metal that came out of one of the holes, possibly part of a drywall screw?  Given the layout of the room, it seems very unlikely that there's any electrical work in this location, so that's my best guess as to what it could be.

The TV is quite heavy and rather expensive so I'd really like to be sure that what I'm mounting it to is, in fact, wood.  Is it possible that the stud finder is wrong?  If so, what can I do to make sure that I'm placing the VESA mount in the right place?  There's really not a better location for the TV.

Comment: There is a stud in there somewhere but right where you are it's most likely you are finding the metal drywall corner bead.  You will probably find the stud about 1" more to the left, more or less.

Comment: that little beam of light is probably pointing to the right edge of the stud ... drywall is on right of it

Comment: use a sewing pin to confirm left edge of the stud .... look at the short horizontal line on the wall ... stick a pin through the wall starting at left end of the line ... if you don't hit wood, then try 1/4 inch to right, and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window that you depict is set into a rough opening that was then banded on with drywall material. In order for that corner to be finished nice and straight the raw edges of the drywall is usually covered with corner bead strip made of metal or plastic. Then drywall mud fills in the corner from both sides and is sanded to a nice corner finish.

In your case you were probably drilling through one flange of a metal corner beading. Typical flange width from the wall corner may be from 1" to 1.5" (25mm to 40mm). Metal ones are made of thin soft steel material. Here is what a common metal corner beading looks like:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.mccoys.com/shop/galvanized-drywall-corner-bead-10/p.110259)*</sup>

Comment: So will the stud be where the stud finder claims?  Or could the stud finder have been mistaking the flange for a stud?

Comment: The stud finder is lighting up the edge of the stud. 3/4" to the left and you're in the middle of the stud.

Comment: @intuited - Keep in mind also that there is going to be a stud right in the corner just behind the drywall. So on that same surface as that stud finder is sitting the edge of the stud toward the window is approximately a half inch in from the corner (the thickness of the drywall that is banding the window opening). The corner bead will also be fastened with nails or screws into this stud.